# The left parenthesis '(' found at 'foo.cpp' was not matched correctly

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Location of the error is indicated in a comment below. Please help fix this.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
class String
{
private:
    enum{sz=80};
    char str[sz];
public:
    String()
    {
        strcpy(str,"");
    }

    String (char s[])
    {
        strcpy(str,s);
    }

    void display() const
    {
        cout<<str;
    }
    String operator +(String ss) const
    {
        String temp;
        if(strlen(str) + (strlen(ss.str) < sz)
        {
            strcpy(temp.str,str);
            strcat(temp.str , ss.str);
        } // Error is reported here!
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nstring overflow";
            exit(1);
        }
        return temp;
    }

};
int main()
{
    String s1="\nMerry christmas";
    String s2="happy new year";
    String s3;

    s1.display();
    s2.display();
    s3.display();

    s3=s1+s2;
    s3.display();
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you using to edit your source code? A good editor will usually point you visually to the right direction.

Comment: You do know about the standard library `string` class, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs here:

```
if(strlen(str) + (strlen(ss.str) < sz)
```

That probably should be:

```
if (strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < sz)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if(strlen(str) + (strlen(ss.str) < sz)
```

should be

```
if(strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < sz)
```

Notice how you have 4 `(` but only 3 `)` in the original line. These need to match up, but they don't. Since the `(` before the second `strlen()` is superfluous (there is no need to wrap `strlen(ss.str)` in brackets), you can remove it.

[Original code with changes to the `#include`s](http://ideone.com/4e2Bh) and [fixed code](http://ideone.com/gCPxh). Note that I had to change the `#include`s from `string.h` to `cstring` for ideone. It's the preferred choice anyway. I also had to add `using namespace std;` as your code wasn't explicitly using the `std` namepsace where required, e.g. using `cout`. You should also [take care of those warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warning).

The reason the compiler error points to 4 lines down is because that's the line where it realises "Oh no, there's a problem here I'm never going to be able to parse this code!" GCC is pretty crappy at error reporting, but a but a compiler (e.g. clang) that does a better job of it would backtrack to the appropriate line where the root cause of the error actually lies and may even suggest a fix for you.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a right parenthesis at the end of this line:

```
if(strlen(str) + (strlen(ss.str) < sz)
```