# Assign a string literal to a char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warnings in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin)

This assignment:

```
char *pc1 = "test string";
```

gives me this warning:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

while this one seems to be fine:

```
char *pc2 = (char*)("test string");
```

Is this one a really better way to proceed?

Notes: for other reasons I cannot use a `const char*`.

Comment: Don't use a C++ compiler for C code.

Comment: You really should be using a `const char *` for this...

Comment: What are those other reasons?

Comment: Which compiler? gcc-4.5.1 doesn't say a word.

Comment: casting away the warning is really a bad idea. Just use `char const*pc1` and everything should be fine.

Comment: You might not want to use `const char*`, but that string literal really is a `const`. You can't modify it.

Comment: As it's C++ code, you could have tagged the question with c++ ... and use `std::string` instead

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, MarceloCantos, DavidHeffernan - I cannot: I must pass it to a function that needs a char*. And I cannot modify that function.

Comment: @pmg You are right, but this is C++ code that calls C functions. So the question is related to the C part of C++.

Comment: @DanielFischer The compiler I am forced to use is gcc 3.4.5

Comment: Note to everyone saying 'don't do it': imagine a C++ project calling an old C library which is not const-correct. The API says that a parameter `char*`, but existing code assigns string literals to it.We know that this has worked for the past 20 years, so can infer that the C library never attempted to change those read-only literals. How do you proceed with new C++ code using the library? Answer: cast away the constness, get on with the real problems.

Answer (score 13):

A string literal is a `const char[]` in C++, and may be stored in read-only memory so your program will crash if you try to modify it.  Pointing a non-const pointer at it is a bad idea.

Comment: Whether or not it is stored in read-only memory, it's UB to modify it. End of story.

Answer (score 8):

In your second example, you must make sure that you don't attempt to modify the the string pointed to by `pc2`.

If you do need to modify the string, there are several alternatives:

1. Make a dynamically-allocated copy of the literal (don't forget to `free()` it when done):

   `char *pc3 = strdup("test string"); /* or malloc() + strcpy() */`
2. Use an array instead of a pointer:

   `char pc4[] = "test string";`

Comment: +1: Although you should point out that `strdup` is not standard C...

Comment: I used `char pc4[] = "test string";` and I get no warnings. I wanted to know if this is the correct way to proceed, or if I am just planting a bug in my code...

Comment: @PietroM: No, you're not planting any bugs, as long as you bear in mind that the allocated array is `strlen("test string")+1` bytes long. If you need a longer array, you can specify the length explicitly: `char pc4[32] = "test string";`

Comment: To be more precise, I used `static char pc4[] = "test string";` and I get no warnings. I did it static because it is inside a function, and I want the string to be available even when out of the function. I wanted to know if this is the correct way to proceed, or if I am just planting a bug in my code...

Answer (score 7):

That depends on whether you need to modify the string literal or not. If yes,

```
char pc1[] = "test string";
```

Comment: That doesn't let you modify the literal, it let's you modify a copy

Comment: Correct. Your comment is precise.