# Struggling with strings. What is wrong with my function?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, string-literals

I am trying to write a small function to trim left spaces from a string, but I cannot get it right. In this version, I get the following error:

> bus error: 10

Could anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am not looking so much for an alternative   piece of code, but would like to understand the errors in my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void trim_string(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *temp = "   I struggle with strings in C.\n";
    trim_string(temp);
    printf("%s", temp);

    return 0;
}


void trim_string(char *string) {
    char *string_trimmed = "";
    int i=0, j=0;

    while (isblank(string[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        string_trimmed[j] = string[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    string_trimmed[j] = '\0';
    strcpy(string, string_trimmed);
}
```

I have now found a workaround solution, shown below. But I am still not very clear about what I did wrong in the first place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

void trim_string(char [MAX_LENGTH]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char temp[MAX_LENGTH] = "   I struggle with strings in C.\n";
    trim_string(temp);
    printf("%s", temp);

    return 0;
}


void trim_string(char string[MAX_LENGTH]) {
    char string_trimmed[MAX_LENGTH];
    int i=0, j=0;

    while (isblank(string[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        string_trimmed[j] = string[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    string_trimmed[j] = '\0';
    printf("c\n");
    strcpy(string, string_trimmed);
}
```

Comment: Had you paid attention to compiler warnings, would you have discovered half of your problem. `char *string_trimmed = "";` should have been `const char *string_trimmed = "";`. But that's not enough - your array is too short.

Comment: I compiled with the following settings and did not get any warning:       gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 trim.c -o trim                                    Which settings do you suggest?

Comment: I always amazed that why I am not getting this warning!

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour [Well, I do](http://ideone.com/FSz7W1), not even a warning, but an error. Same with `clang` (some versions, anyway).

Comment: @H2CO3 Full program [no warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6b059cf178d053b) your warning is for an unused variable.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Fair enough, that's for a unused variable. But maybe because it stopped due to the first warning (which is treated as an error). Whatever. It really should be a warning, and string literals aren't to be modified.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour [Here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin), IDK why this was taken out from `-Wall`, it's a really nasty error.

Answer (score 1):

Both `string` and `string_trimmed` point to string literals, here in `main`:

```
char *temp = "   I struggle with strings in C.\n";
             ^
             |
             This is a string literal
```

`temp` points to a *string literal* and the standard says you are not allowed to modify them.

In the function `trim_string` you are modifying a them which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) of which a bus error is one possible result, although anything can happen.

`string_trimmed` either needs to be an array like this:

```
char string_trimmed[n] ;
```

where `n` is the size of your input using `strlen(string)` would probably make sense or dynamically allocated via `malloc` which you would need to free at the end of your function. The same things goes for your input from `main`, this would work as a substitute:

```
char temp[] = "   I struggle with strings in C.\n";
```

For completeness sake, the draft C99 standard section `6.4.5` *String literals* paragraph *6* says (*emphasis mine*):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.**