# Disable warning "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]"

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw32, string-literals

I have these two lines in my code:

```
RFM2G_STATUS   result;   
result = RFM2gOpen( "\\\\.\\rfm2g1", &rH );
```

I get the error message:

```
"warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
     result = RFM2gOpen( "\\\\.\\rfm2g1", &rH );"
```

Actually I can not modify it to

```
const RFM2G_STATUS   result;
```

because `RFM2G_STATUS` is pre-defined in another file and does not accept const before. Is there another way to disable this warning message?

Comment: Please state what the signature of `RFM2gOpen()` is.

Comment: this is the definition of this function in the other file   STDRFM2GCALL RFM2gOpen(char *DevicePath, RFM2GHANDLE *rh);

Comment: Assuming gcc then see [How to get rid of `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warnings in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59670/1708801)

Comment: No reason for this to have the 'Qt' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be absolutely sure that `RFM2gOpen` does not modify the input string, otherwise you would have undefined behavior in your code as it stands now.

If you are sure that the input data will not be written to, you can `const_cast` the constness away safely:

```
result = RFM2gOpen(const_cast<char*>("\\\\.\\rfm2g1"), &rH );
```

Again, this is only safe if the routine does *not* write to the input string, ever, otherwise this is undefined behavior!

If you are not completely sure that this method will never write to the character array, copy the string to an `std::vector<char>` and pass the `.data()` pointer to the function (or use a simple `char` array as [Bo Persson suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377425/3002139), that would most likely be more efficient/appropriate than the `vector`).

Answer (score 2):

Like the message says, conversion from `const char*` to `char*` (which C++ inherited from ancient C language which didn't have `const`) has been deprecated.

To avoid this, you can store the parameter in a non-const string, and pass that to the function:

```
char parameter[] = "\\\\.\\rfm2g1";
RFM2G_STATUS   result;   
result = RFM2gOpen( parameter, &rH );
```

That way you avoid the ugly casts.

Answer (score 1):

One possible fix is:

```
RFM2gOpen(const_cast<char*>("\\.\rfm2g1"), &rH);
```

This may cause a runtime fault if `RFM2gOpen` tries to modify the string.

The following is less likely to cause a memory fault, but it still undefined behavior:

```
std::string s("\\.\rfm2g1");
RFM2gOpen(const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()), &rH);
```

To be fully conformant you need to copy the "\.\rfm2g1" to a mutable buffer. Something like:

```
char *s = alloca(strlen("\\.\rfm2g1")+1);
strcpy(s, "\\.\rfm2g1");
RFM2gOpen(s, &rH);
```

The real fix, of course, is for `RFM2gOpen` to be updated to take a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the function `RFM2gOpen()` expects a non-const `char*` as first parameter ([see here](http://www.veldamour.com/files/rfm2g_common.pdf)), as it can sometimes happen with legacy API's (or API's written by lazy coders), and string litterals are of type `const char*`
 so a deprecated implicit conversion is happening (getting rid of the const qualifier).

If you're *100% sure that the function won't modify the pointed-to memory, then *and* *only* *then* can you just put an explicit conversion, e.g. `const_cast<char*>("\\\\.\\rfm2g1")` or (C-style) `(const char*)"\\\\.\\rfm2g1"`