# Conversion from string constant, pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

After reading several answers I have corrected my code to as follows;

```
int main()
{
    // a pointer to char is initialized with a string literal

    char Buffer[100];

    cout << "Enter an initial string: " << endl;
    cin >> Buffer;
    cout << "Original content of Buffer:--> " << Buffer << endl;


    cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;
    cin >> Buffer;



    gets(Buffer);
    cout << "Now the Buffer contains:--> " << Buffer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know longer have the warning code, but now the program doesnt execute as I would like. The last part does not output my new sentance.

I know people mentioned not to use gets, but I tried using getline, obviously I cant use it as a direct replacement so I was a bit lost.

Any suggestions

Comment: It's a good idea to ask the compiler to treat that warning as an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of \`deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char\*’\` warnings in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin)

Comment: You'll need either `std::strcpy` (to make a deep copy) or `std::string`. You cannot modify a string literal. `char Buffer[] = "Dummy content.";` is also a way.

Comment: @Logicstuff, sorry when you say I need it, where would I put it in the code?

Comment: You are in C++, don't use `char *`, use strings; don't use `gets`, use `cin >>` or streams functions. Choose the world your in, don't mix C I/Os with C++'s.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n`' starts a new line.

Comment: Re: "use gets() to get the whole line" -- use `std::getline()` to get the whole line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify string literral. Your way of coding is too much "C style". 
If the original buffer content doesn't matter and you must use `gets()`, don't initialize your buffer :

```
char Buffer[100];
cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;

gets(Buffer);
cout << "Now the Buffer contains:--> " << endl;
cout << Buffer << endl;
```

Don't forget that if you input more than 100 characters (as the size of the buffer), this will also crash.

As gets is deprecated, fgets must be encouraged : it protects you from overflows. You should code this way in C-Style :

```
char buffer[10];
printf("Your sentence : \n");
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
printf("Your sentence : %s\n", buffer);
```

Ouputs :

> Your sentence : 
>   1 34 6789012345
>   Your sentence : 1 34 6789

Nonetheless, you should consider using `std::cin` with `std::string` to make correct C++ inputs :

```
std::string sentence;
std::cout << "Enter a sentence (with spaces): ";
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
std::cout << "Your sentence (with spaces): " << sentence << std::endl;
```

Outputs :

> Enter a sentence (with spaces): My super sentence 
>   Your sentence (with spaces): My super sentence

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not entirely working. When it prompts me to enter a sentance, I do so, but then the output is just 'Now the buffer contains :-->' and my string is gone

Comment: I am trying to show you my now modified code so you can see, but having difficulties putting it into a comment without it being a block of text...

Comment: Don't try to put code in comment, but add it at the end of your question instead. Put a title like "Edit after A. Ocannaille answer" Or something like that. Then your new code, then an explication of your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read into a memory which contains string constant. Often those string constants are stored in read-only memory and even if not, they can share the constants so you would override one string for all parts of your code.

You need to copy the string into some buffer and then do whatever you want. For example:

```
const char *myOrigBuffer = "Dummy string";
char buffer[1024];
strcpy(buff, myOrigBuffer);
....
gets(buff);
```

Comment: Thanks Zbynek, I have edited my program to try and incorporate your suggestions but it is still not working.... how do I add code in a comment lol

Comment: @FrankWhite: You don't.  You update the question.  (Probably leaving the old code in place, and adding the new code.  You must also clarify what "not working" means: Hangs, error, what?  Also, learn to use a debugger.  You will find the problem very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal like `"Dummy content."` is logically `const`, since any operation that attempts to change its contents results in undefined behaviour.

The definition/initialisation

```
char *Buffer = "Dummy content.";
```

however, makes `Buffer` a non-`const` pointer to (the first character of) a string literal.   That involves a conversion (from array of `const char` to a `char *`).  That conversion exists in C for historical reasons so is still in C++.   However, subsequently using `Buffer` to modify the string literal - which is what `gets(Buffer)` does unless the user enters no data - still gives undefined behaviour.

Your "stopped working" error is one manifestation of undefined behaviour.

Giving undefined behaviour is the reason the conversion is deprecated.

Note:  `gets()` is more than deprecated.   It has been removed from the C standard, from where it originated, completely because it is so dangerous (no way to prevent it overwriting arbitrary memory).   In C++, use `getline()` instead.   It is often not a good idea to mix C I/O function and C++ stream functions on the same input or output device (or file) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> char *Buffer = "Dummy content.";

You should use pointer on const char here because "Dummy content." is not a buffer but pointer on string literal that has type "array of n const char" and static storage duration, so cannot be changed through pointer. Correct variant is:

```
char const* Literal = "Dummy content.";
```

But you cannot use it as parameter for `gets`

> gets(Buffer);

It is bad idea and should cause write access exception or memory corruption on writing. You should pass to `gets` a pointer to a block of memory where received string will be stored.
This block should have enough length to store whole string, so in general `gets` is unsafe, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/2139056 for more info. 
But as temporary test solution you can use buffer on stack:

```
char Buffer[256];
gets(Buffer);
```

or dynamic allocated buffer:

```
char* Buffer= new char[256];
gets(Buffer);
//and do not forget to free memory after your output operations
delete [] Buffer;
```