# How can I solve this error with deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char'?

Tags: c

After I compile it, it gives me an error on (ps:i am using devc++ 5.9.2 as the compiler, and one my friend use dev c++ 5.1.1, and she is able to compile).

> [Warning] Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

```
void switchSecondSelection(int selection){
int secondSelection;

    switch(selection){
    case 1:
    subMenu("Supplier Info",1);
 //   return secondSelection;
    break;
    case 2:
    subMenu("Customer Info",2);
 //   return secondSelection;
    break;
    case 3:
    subMenu("Medicine Info",3);

//  return secondSelection;
    break;
    case 4:
//      secondSelection = showReport("Report");
   break;
    case 5:
//      secondSelection = showBill("Bill");
    break;
    case 6:
    mainProgram(0);
    break;
    default:
    mainProgram(0);
    break;
}
```

Comment: devc++ is **not** a compiler. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: By defining `subMenu` to take a `const char*` argument.

Comment: Hi, Weather Vane, but how? i am still a Semester 1 Student in C,can u show me the code?

Comment: Not until you show the function yourself.

Comment: @Tohsiba if you are new here, please note that you flag someone by putting the `at` symbol before their name, like I did in this comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane
void subMenu(char title[256],int category); << you mean here? subMenu(const char title[256],int category);? but after i had changed the information, another error show up , and when i put in    subMenu const ("Supplier Info",1); and its say [Error] expected ';' before 'const'

Comment: Please post your code *in the question*, properly formatted and quoting the *exact* error message. In your comment it looks as though you have changed the function declaration (prototype). You also need to change the function definition (implementation).

Comment: "i am still a Semester 1 Student in C" - What a lame excuse! There are enough C books available for free. If in doubt ask your teacher, that's what he is paid for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of \`deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char\*’\` warnings in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin)

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your `subMenu` function, but it most likely takes a `char *` as its first argument.  Because it is not `const`, the function is free to modify what that argument points to.  That doesn't work however for string constants which typically reside in a read-only section of memory.

Change the definition of `subMenu` to take a `const char *` for the first argument.

EDIT:

Find where `subMenu` is defined.  It probably looks something like this:

```
void subMenu(char *name, int value)
```

Change it to this:

```
void subMenu(const char *name, int value)
```

Comment: can you show me the code? and how should i do it to change the definition of subMenu to take a const char? ,because i am still a Semester 1 student in C and i have no ideas how to complete this assignment

Comment: nt mainMenu();
void subMenu(char title[256],int category); << you mean here? subMenu(const char title[256],int category);? but after i had changed the information, another error show up , and when i put in    subMenu const ("Supplier Info",1); and its say [Error] expected ';' before 'const'

Comment: @Tohsiba  Look closely at what I wrote.  I didn't say to put `const` after the function name when you call it.  I said to put `const` right before `char` in the definition, i.e. `void subMenu(const char title[256],int category);`.  This is the declaration, so you also need to change the definition which is where the body of the function `subMenu` is.