# Reading objects from text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read from a text file properties: char* and int and create objects of class B.Here is my implementation:

```
 B * p=new B[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    p[i]=B("John",300);

}
ofstream file("example.txt");

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    file<<p[i].getName()<<" "<<p[i].GetValue()<<endl;      
}
file.close();
  //saved succesfully

 ifstream file2("example.txt");

B *q=new B[3];
char* temp;
int time1;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    file2>>temp>>time1;
    char*name1=new char[strlen(temp)+1];
    strcpy(name1,temp); //here name1 is red correctly
   q[i]=B(name1,time1); // 
}
file2.close();
```

The saving of the 3 objects is successful ,I have checked the file.However when I am reading from it 3 objects,the first object is correctly created ,but for the other objects the char* propery which I pass gets initialized as "," and the second parameter which is int is also correct.Why does the first object create successfully while the others don't?

Comment: If you are permitted use std::string instead of cstrings.

Comment: I cannot use string.

Comment: `char* temp;` needs to be initialized before reading.

Comment: The above code probably produces memory leaks. You need to `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: ***Why does the first object create successfully while the others don't?*** Undefined behavior caused by the uninitialized pointer dereference.

Comment: Try writing code without `new` or `delete` first.  You should use `new` when allocating memory during run-time when the quantity is input by the User.

Answer (score 3):

`file2 >> temp` is invalid as `temp` is an uninitialized pointer. This `operator>>` needs a preallocated buffer.

I recommend using less 'stars' (zero, ideally) and more standard containers, i.e. `std::vector` and `std::string` in this case. That will also solve your memory leaks...

Ok, if you cannot, implement your own functionality-restricted version of `std::string`. Anything else violates [The single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and that's not good C++.

If you don't want to go that far, a simple fix is to make `temp` an actual array with the size of the maximum number of characters you expect the names in the file to be.

---

Lastly, think about whether you can make `B::name` `char const*`, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin).

Comment: Yes, of course using string and vector makes the things easier,but I am not allowed to use them.

Comment: I have made it a buffer with a particular size and deleted at the end pointers and the program runs sucessfully

Comment: That is most likely what your teacher is looking for. A little frustrating that you can not use `c++`..