# how to fix : argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, char

I got this error while doing OpenGL project

> const char * is incompatible with parameter of type char *

```
//  variables representing the window size
int window_width = 706;
int window_height = 706;
//  variable representing the window title
const char *window_title = "Snake";
void init_setup(int width, int height, char *windowName)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    centerOnScreen();
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);// init. window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(window_x, window_y); // init. window position
    glutCreateWindow(windowName);   // window name
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape_handler);  // sets the reshape call back
}    // end of init_setup()

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
init_setup(window_width, window_height, window_title); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Remove const before const char * window_title or add const into init_setup(..., const char *windowName)

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: There is no need to double space between code lines.

Comment: See related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59670/1735922

Comment: it works thanks! :3

Comment: @rAndom69 "*Remove `const` before `const char * window_title`*" - that won't work since string literals are `const` data and cannot be assigned to non-const pointers.