# why the warining deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' occured in the bellow program

Tags: c++, string, char-pointer

I created a class called person with the public member function fill_data which takes two arguments as char array and int . I passed the arguments like this fill_data("tushar",30); but there shows a warning 
 deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' 
but I don't understand why, if any help me to know
|

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class person
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    public:
    void fill_data(char name2[],int age2)
    {
        strcpy(name,name2);
        age=age2;
    }
    void display_data(void)
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
        cout<<age<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    person p1;
    p1.fill_data("tushar",30);
    p1.display_data();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You passed the string constant `"tushar"` to the function parameter `char name2[]`, which is non-const. So in order to do this, the compiler had to convert the string constant to a `char *` (versus a `const char *`), which is deprecated.

If `fill_data` is not going to modify `name2`, the parameter should be `const`. If `fill_data` is going to modify whatever is passed as the `name2` parameter, don't pass it a constant like `"tushar"`.

Make up your mind and code one or the other.