# Output of a 2-d array needs to be understood

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic

This is the code 
https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/8bYOzDDC9U to run this

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *c[] = {"GeksQuiz", "MCQ", "TEST", "QUIZ"};
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp = cp;

int main()
{
    cpp++;
    printf("%s", cpp[0][0]);  // TEST
    printf("%s ", cpp[-1][-1]); // TEST
    return 0;
}
```

The output of both the printf() is TEST. Why is it so? When I do cpp++, the pointer moves to c+2. SO I understand that cpp[0][0] will be at the starting of "TEST" and that's why it is printing TEST. 
Can someone explain me for cpp[-1[-1]?

Comment: In C++ you should not assign a string literal to `char*` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin

Comment: `cpp[-1][-1]` is Undefined Behavior because `-1` is outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: Sorry. It's a C language

Comment: Also I don't know if you are used to Python, but in C indexing `[-1]` is not the back of the array, if that's what you are trying to do

Comment: btw this is something you need to understand if you want to become a [three-star-programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), for everything else you should rather write code that is easier to write, read and understand

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's what I am trying to understand

Comment: @AkhileshGangwar Being a three-star programmer is generally a bad thing.

Comment: don't try to learn or get inspiration from that that geeky site. I don't know how it is for C, but whenever I read there something on C++ i am shocked.

Comment: @0x5453 Before that the pointer is incremented by 1

Comment: @0x5453: `cpp[-1][-1]` has no undefined behavior. Pointer arithmetic with negative integers is defined by the C standard as long as the results point to elements of arrays or one beyond the end of an array, and these operations do.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am trying to get my hands on pointers. SO I tried to solve some questions. And I stuck there.

Comment: I have posted the link also from where I got this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, sorry removed the faulty comment

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good catch, I missed the `cpp++` above that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char ***cpp = cp;` initializes `cpp` to point to the first element of `cp`, that is, `cp[0]`.

After `cpp++`, `cpp` points to `cp[1]`. Then `cpp[-1]` refers to `cp[0]`.

`cp[0]` contains `c+3`, which is a pointer to `c[3]`. So `cp[0][-1]` refers to `c[2]`.

`c[2]` contains `"Test"`, in the sense that it is a pointer to the first element of `"Test"`, so printing it prints `"Test"`.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the pointer `cpp` points to the first element of the array `cp`.

```
char ***cpp = cp;
```

After this statement

```
cpp++;
```

the pointer `cpp` points to the second element of the array `cp`. So this expression

```
cpp[-1]
```

gives the first element of the array `cp`

Pay attention to that the expression `cpp[-1]` is calculated like

```
*( cpp - 1 )
```

Thus in fact these two statements

```
cpp++;
```

and

```
cpp[-1]
```

may be considered like `*( ( cpp += 1 ) - 1 )` that has the same effect if to write `cpp[0]` without incrementing the pointer `cpp`.

This (first ) element of the array `cp`. contains the value `c+3` that is the pointer to the last element of the array c.

So `cpp[-1][-1]`give the element before the last element of the array `c` that is the pointer to the first character of the string literal `"TEST"`.

Thus the string literal is outputted by this call of printf

```
printf("%s ", cpp[-1][-1])
```

Also bear in mind that in the presented code there is neither 2-d array. All arrays, `c` and `cp`,  are one-dimensional arrays of pointers.

Comment: How can we consider cpp++ and cpp[-1] as cpp[0] ? This is something I don't understand in terms of pointers.

Comment: @AkhileshGangwar Consider x + 1 - 1. What is the result? It is in fact the same as cpp++ - 1 because the result of cpp++ is cpp + 1.

Comment: I was assuming something else. :P Thanks. I got it. :)